# How to reuse a package multiple times in a config?

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I have a general camera config yaml, where the only thing that usually changes between specific cameras is the IP address. Some fields (in the following example `fps`) remain the same.

Can I do something like this in Hydra/OmegaConf?

`any_camera.yaml`

```
any_camera:
  stream_url: ???
  fps: 25
```

`all_cameras.yaml`

```
all_cameras:
  cam1:
    @{any_camera}
    stream_url: rtsp://10.0.0.1

  cam2:
    @{any_camera}
    stream_url: rtsp://10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two potential options:

1. In Hydra you can try:  [extending configs](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/extending_configs) and [select_multiple_configs_from_config_group](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group)

Basically you could have cam1 and cam2 both extend from any_camera and have specific overrides.
Then in all_cameras.yaml, you can select multiple config groups to have the config list.

2. You can also look into omegaconf's [node interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#variable-interpolation). But that might require you change the cam config's structure.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer to using the same config more than once is to override the config package.

```yaml
defaults:
 - server/db@src: mysql
 - server/db@dst: mysql
```

Will result in the content of server/db/mysql.yaml in two places in the config object, src and dst.

See [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages#using-a-config-group-more-than-once) section in the packages page.

Comment: But then how do I override part, but not all of src and dst?

Comment: From a command line or from another config file. If you want define a new version of a config see the link from Jieru about extending configs.